# How to make disable right click function in angular called from any component

Tags: angular

```
<div class="container" (contextmenu)="onRightClick()">
</div>
```

I want to disable right click in a few components and not the whole website. I have to define the below function in all the components where I want to disable right click.
What's the best way to do it so that I don't have to define the function again and again in those components

```
onRightClick() {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's the `contextmenu` event : create a directive to manage that.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryh715)

```
@HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])
onRightClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: returning `false` from the method will also do like `onRightClick(event) {
    return false;
  }`. So, if possible can you suggest which one is better.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar [look for it on google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 14):

My advice is to make a directive that will have click binded to element where it is attached.
You got small tutorial on their official documentation and it should give you clear path on what you should make.

In this case, you can reuse directive all over your app and will do just the same thing. Will bind click to element where it is attached and will have some logic in it, so you don't repeat yourself.

[doc](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#write-the-directive-code)

Example:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDisableRightClick]'
})
export class DisableRightClickDirective {
  @HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])
  onRightClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

you can also make module that will export this directive and in order to use it in your other modules, just import that module. Modules should look like the following:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DisableRightClickDirective } from './disable-right-click.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DisableRightClickDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    DisableRightClickDirective
  ]
})
export class DisableRightClickModule {
}
```

In every module, where you'd like to use this directive, all you have to do is import `DisableRightClickModule`. And that's pretty much it.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DisableRightClickModule } from './disable-right-click.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ....,
    DisableRightClickModule
  ]
})
export class SomeDummyModule {
}
```

Inside your HTML just attach directive to any element as attribute eg.

```
<a href="#" appDisableRightClick>
```

Comment: it is working. thanks. just add on for new in angular. need to add above given selector appDisableRightClick on html element ex: <div appDisableRightClick> or <a href="" appDisableRightClick>  :)

Comment: thanks for suggestion :) will do just now!

Answer (score 5):

you can easily do like below:

```html
<div class="container" (contextmenu)="onRightClick()"></div>
```

```js
onRightClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

note: this code only disable right click for the div you referred.
If you want to disable for all page you can use:

```js
@HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])
  onRightClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: This answer fits for my situation, I only need to disable right-click on few components. If you need to disable in the whole project, create a directive.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested to disable right click on entire Angular app, use below in index.html file.
`<body class="mat-typography" oncontextmenu="return false">`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a script to disable right click & F12 functions.
Add below script in index.html that is in root path in your angular application.

First, add **oncontextmenu="return false;"** as a HTML attribute for `<body>` tag as below.

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

> Your `<app-root></app-root>` goes next to the `<body>` tag*

Then, add below script before close `<body>` tag.

```
<script>document.addEventListener("contextmenu",e=>e.preventDefault()),document.onkeydown=function(e){return 123!=e.keyCode&&((!e.ctrlKey||!e.shiftKey||73!=e.keyCode)&&((!e.ctrlKey||!e.shiftKey||74!=e.keyCode)&&((!e.ctrlKey||85!=e.keyCode)&&void 0)))};</script>
```

Finaly, close `</body>` tag & serve your application again.

Answer (score 1):

Can someone explain why a directive solution is better then simple saying oncontextmenu="return false"

```
@HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])
  onRightClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

With a directive you would have to load the directive anytime you are using it to a specific module. I could see that a directive makes sense if you are doing things other than simply disabling the contextmenu. I would like to understand why the directive  implementation is more effective than simply saying contextmenu="return false;" mycontextmenudirective vs contextmenu="return false;"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34098664)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me without Hostistner.
(contextmenu)="$event?.preventDefault();"